# Variable Empty until Reassigned

Tags: php

I am not quite sure why this is happening, or how to properly explain it, but maybe someone can shed some light on this.

I have a CMS system I based off of the CodeIgniter/Opencart Framework utilizing a Registry, Controller and Module. I have run into a scenario where I have previously saved a variable to the registry as:

```
$this->application_page = 'current/page';
```

But for some reason when I call it in the application:

```
echo empty($this->application_page)?'yes':'no';
//Returns Yes
```

But.. When I Reassign it:

```
echo empty($this->application_page)?'yes':'no';
//Returns Yes

$page = $this->application_page;
echo empty($page)?'yes':'no';
//Returns No
```

A var_dump returns:

```
var_dump($this->application_page);
string 'current/page' (length=12)
```

I can get around this quite easily by just using `$page` but I'm curious to know why this is happening?

**UPDATE:**

So I messed around with the `_isset` function but didn't get it to work, possibly my error, possibly not.. Here is how it all works together:

```
class Registry {
  private $data = array();
  public function get($key){ return (isset($this->data[$key]) ? $this->data[$key] : NULL); }
  public function set($key,$val){ $this->data[$key] = $val;
}

abstract class Controller {
  protected $registry;
  public function __construct($registry){ $this->registry = $registry; }
  public function __get($key){ return $this->registry->get($key); }
  public function __set($key,$value){ $this->registry->set($key, $value); }
}

class Applications {
  private $registry;
  function __construct($Registry){ $this->registry = $Registry; }
  function __get($key){ return $this->registry->get($key); }
  function __set($key,$val){ return $this->registry->set($key,$val); }
  public function buildApplication(){
      $this->application_page = 'current/page';
      $application = new application($this->registry);
  }

}

class Application extends Controller {
  public function index(){
    echo empty($this->application_page)?'yes':'no';
    //Returns Yes

    $page = $this->application_page;
    echo empty($page)?'yes':'no';
    //Returns No
  }
}
```

Hopefully this helps?
*Had a Typo, Registry's functions are not magic methods. Also $registry was declared in Applications.*

Comment: Are you 100% sure you didn't have a typo in you var names while testing this?

Comment: Sorry about the delay! Yes I am sure, I double checked about 5 times before I posted =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class probably didn't implement the magic [__isset()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.isset) method which is triggered by calling [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) or [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) on inaccessible properties.

---

Example:

[Live demo I](http://ideone.com/kqM5yn):

```
<?php

class Test {
    private $a = '42';

    public function __get($name) {
        return $this->a;
    }
}

$obj = new Test();
var_dump($obj->a);        // string(2) "42"
var_dump(empty($obj->a)); // bool(true)
```

Implementing the [__isset()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.isset) method as follows ([Live demo II](http://ideone.com/irlyVf)) will yield the correct result:

```
public function __isset($name) {
    if ($name == 'a') {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// ...
var_dump($obj->a);        // string(2) "42"
var_dump(empty($obj->a)); // bool(false)
```

---

Here is a new version of your code implementing the [__isset()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.isset) methods: http://ideone.com/rJekJV

Change log:

- Added `__isset()` method to *Controller* class which internally calls `Registry::has()`.
- Added `has()` method to *Registy* class.
- [Only for testing: Object initialization and running `Application::index()` method.]

There was one issue (after updating your answer):

- You haven't declared `$registry` as a member variable in the *Applications* class.
  The code fails otherwise because it doesn't access the actual member variable (magic [__set()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set) method!)
- Also, you had quite some redundancy in your code (not DRY). I hope this isn't production code ;)

Comment: Sorry, there were a few typo's in my post: __set & __get were actually get set & get. There was also $registry set in Applications. Do you recommend getting rid of the "data" variable in the registry and just using the __isset. This part was copied from the opencart framework

Comment: @Corey I've updated my answer. If you want to get rid of `Registry::$data`, where else do you want to save the registry data? My recommendation: either use `__get(), __set(), __isset()` or something like `get(), set(), has()`.

Comment: @CornFreek True - I don't know what I was thinking it's getting late! Thanks again for all your help, As cheesy as it makes me sound, I'm surprised this wasn't in the code I copied it from =P